# how to handle the signinwithemailandpassword not a function error to login to react project with firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

*Firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword is not a function

this error is displayed everytime i try to sign in to my react project with firebase.
i tried using the auth object in different ways as well as verified the password n email registered with firebase. how to handle this error

one i click the signin button its supposed to sign in which is not happening. tried different ways of checking the auth object, logged on console yet the function is not available

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)